# What is NamedTemporaryFile useful for on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

The Python module `tempfile` contains both `NamedTemporaryFile` and `TemporaryFile`. The documentation for the former says

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later)

What is the point of the file having a name if I can't use that name? If I want the useful (for me) behaviour of Unix on Windows, I've got to make a copy of the code and rip out all the bits that say `if _os.name == 'nt'` and the like.

What gives? Surely this is useful for something, since it was deliberately coded this way, but what is that something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It states that accessing it a second time while it is still *open*.  You can still use the name otherwise, just be sure to pass `delete=False` when creating the `NamedTemporaryFile` so that it persists after it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```py
import os, tempfile, gc


class TemporaryFile:
    def __init__(self, name, io, delete):
        self.name = name
        self.__io = io
        self.__delete = delete

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        return getattr(self.__io, k)

    def __del__(self):
        if self.__delete:
            try:
                os.unlink(self.name)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass


def NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', bufsize=-1, suffix='', prefix='tmp', dir=None, delete=True):
    if not dir:
        dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    name = os.path.join(dir, prefix + os.urandom(32).hex() + suffix)
    if mode is None:
        return TemporaryFile(name, None, delete)
    fh = open(name, "w+b", bufsize)
    if mode != "w+b":
        fh.close()
        fh = open(name, mode)
    return TemporaryFile(name, fh, delete)


def test_ntf_txt():
    x = NamedTemporaryFile("w")
    x.write("hello")
    x.close()
    assert os.path.exists(x.name)
    with open(x.name) as f:
        assert f.read() == "hello"


def test_ntf_name():
    x = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="s", prefix="p")
    assert os.path.basename(x.name)[0] == 'p'
    assert os.path.basename(x.name)[-1] == 's'
    x.write(b"hello")
    x.seek(0)
    assert x.read() == b"hello"


def test_ntf_del():
    x = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="s", prefix="p")
    assert os.path.exists(x.name)
    name = x.name
    del x
    gc.collect()
    assert not os.path.exists(name)


def test_ntf_mode_none():
    x = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="s", prefix="p", mode=None)
    assert not os.path.exists(x.name)
    name = x.name
    f = open(name, "w")
    f.close()
    assert os.path.exists(name)
    del x
    gc.collect()
    assert not os.path.exists(name)
```

works on all platforms, you can close it, open it up again, etc.

The feature `mode=None` is what you want, you can ask for a tempfile, specify `mode=None`, which gives you a UUID styled temp name with the dir/suffix/prefix that you want.   The link references tests that show usage.

It's basically the same as NamedTemporaryFile, except the file will get auto-deleted when the object returned is garbage collected... not on close.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to "rip out all the bits...".  It's coded like that for a reason. It says you can't open it a SECOND time while it's still open.   Don't.  Just use it once, and throw it away (after all, it is a temporary file).  If you want a permanent file, create your own.

"Surely this is useful for something, since it was deliberately coded this way, but what is that something".  Well, I've used it to write emails to (in a binary format) before copying them to a location where our Exchange Server picks them up & sends them.  I'm sure there are lots of other use cases.

Comment: But that use case is satisfied by the non-Windows behaviour too... basically you can do everything you can on Windows *plus* reopen the file while the file is open. Which means that one can use `delete=True` to clean up. So I guess not useless, just less useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Python library writers didn't just decide to make `NamedTemporaryFile` behave differently on Windows for laughs. All those `_os.name == 'nt'` tests will be there because of platform differences between Windows and Unix. So my inference from that documentation is that on Windows a file opened the way `NamedTemporaryFile` opens it *cannot* be opened again while `NamedTemporaryFile` still has it open, and that this is due to the way **Windows** works.

Comment: It can, just use open("rbD") to reopen it instead of open("rb"). See the mscvrt documentation for `fopen()` flags.